# Generated Data Label values from worksheet sometimes don't show

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am generating values in Excel 2010, initially putting them into an array, then copying them into a worksheet for use as datalabels for a logarithmix x-axis (actually calling Chart Labeller to do that, but this also happens when i manually apply through Excel). For the most part this works fine without problems. In certain instances, however, some, but not all, of the data labels do not visible show, even though the data in the worksheet is there, manually selecting the data labels shows an invisible label selected.

What I found out, and I think this may be a bug in Excel, when I go to the worksheet, and re-type in the value that is not showing up on the chart, it then shows up on the chart.

Here are my dim's for the array:

```
Dim chart_labeler_info_x()
```

Here is how I populate the array:

```
'Assuming we are going to do the x-axis

ReDim chart_labeler_info_x(1 To x_axis_interval_num, 1 To 3)
For k = 1 To x_axis_interval_num
    'Column 1 is the new chart label value, column 2 is the y value of the new series , column 3 is the x value(equivalent to 111...)

    '--------------------------------------------------------
    chart_labeler_info_x(k, 1) = suf_ize(10 ^ (Log(x_axis.MinimumScale) / Log(10#) + (k - 1)))
    chart_labeler_info_x(k, 2) = y_axis.MinimumScale
    chart_labeler_info_x(k, 3) = 10 ^ (Log(x_axis.MinimumScale) / Log(10#) + (k - 1))
    '--------------------------------------------------------
Next k
```

Here is how I initialize the range on the worksheet:

```
Set new_labeler_ws_x_axis = Sheets.Add
new_labeler_ws_x_axis.Name = Chart_for_series & "Eng_Labels_X_Axis"

new_labeler_ws_x_axis.Range("a1:c" & x_axis_interval_num).Value = chart_labeler_info_x
new_labeler_ws_x_axis.Range("a1:c" & x_axis_interval_num).Font.Name = "Arial"
new_labeler_ws_x_axis.Range("a1:c" & x_axis_interval_num).Font.Size = 7
```

I also create a new series attached to this range:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .XValues = Sheets(new_labeler_ws_x_axis.Name).Range("C1:C" & x_axis_interval_num)
    .Values = Sheets(new_labeler_ws_x_axis.Name).Range("B1:B" & x_axis_interval_num)
    .Name = "=""Labeller_x"""
    .Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Format.line.Visible = True
End With
```

The data that is generated in the worksheet looks like this:

```
1m          100 0.001
10m         100 0.01
100m        100 0.1
1           100 1
10          100 10
100         100 100
1k          100 1000
```

Column 1 has the values that will be used as the new data labels. Column 2 is the y-value, Column 3 is the actual x-value. (I can attach the worksheet if that helps.)

Here is an image of what I am talking about:

[image: Chart labels]

You notice that the 1k data label that should be there, is not visible.

I can make the 1k data label appear one of two ways:

1. Extend the maximum value for the series, in this case to 10,000 (10k) in which case the 1k label shows.
2. Manually go to the worksheet, select the cell that has the 1000 value, re-enter the value 1000 and press return, the data label then shows up as 1k.

Some other interesting anomalies, when the maximum value is 100, the data label for 100 disappears also. As the maximum value is increased beyond 1000, there seems to be no problems the data labels all show themselves.

I have tried changing the number format, which general, to number, with two decimal places, no luck. Changing to text and back, no luck.

I think this is a bug, but haven't found in info, can any of the experts out there shine some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, while somewhat of a hack, i think it underlines what the problem may actually be, and maybe someone can suggest a more elegant solution.

I added the last line of this code block:

```
    chart_labeler_info_x(k, 1) = suf_ize(10 ^ (Log(x_axis.MinimumScale) / Log(10#) + (k - 1)))
    chart_labeler_info_x(k, 2) = y_axis.MinimumScale
    chart_labeler_info_x(k, 3) = 10# ^ (Log(x_axis.MinimumScale) / Log(10#) + (k - 1#))
    'This line did the trick
    If chart_labeler_info_x(k, 3) >= 1 Then chart_labeler_info_x(k, 3) = Round(chart_labeler_info_x(k, 3), 0)
```

As i said previously, we had found that manually updating the value in the cell, caused the labels to be visible. We tried applying the Round function to the value in the cell, and that worked, so i put it as a check in the code, for values of 1 and higher.

It appears that, even though the cell value shown is 1000, internally, it must not be. (I checked .value and .value2, they both reported 1000.) The bug i think lies in this happening SOMETIMES. If the maximum value of the series is increased, the 1k label appears, even though it it the same math being used to generate the values.

Maybe someone can explain why this is happening and offer a more elegant solution!

Thanks,

Russ